(Flutter Android) ImageTextureEntry can't wait on the fence on Android < 33
I'm trying to use this package: multiple_image_camera. It allows user to take multiple pictures from camera. image_picker allows only single at a time.
I/CameraManagerGlobal( 5873): Connecting to camera service
W/Camera  ( 5873): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by Android. Defaulting to yuv420
I/Camera  ( 5873): startPreview
I/Camera  ( 5873): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  ( 5873): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  ( 5873): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  ( 5873): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
D/EGL_emulation( 5873): app_time_stats: avg=355.87ms min=10.27ms max=2029.45ms count=7
W/ImageReaderSurfaceProducer( 5873): ImageTextureEntry can't wait on the fence on Android < 33

When I click on capture button:
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873): Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873): android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:507: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1179)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:99)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1287)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:579)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:790)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:259)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873): Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:507: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38) (code 10)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2439)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:749)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
E/CameraCaptureSession( 5873):  ... 9 more
I/Camera  ( 5873): open | onDisconnected
I/Camera  ( 5873): close
I/Camera  ( 5873): open | onClosed

It works perfectly well on Android 13+. How can I make it work for Android <13?

Use https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera-deprecated/cameradirect for android < 13

@BobSmith is anything available for flutter? I don't think I can use that

Mohit for that you need to first post the code you are using. This link may help you https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera
